# I need to find out the overlap between 37 terms

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a large dataframe in R (about 180,000 rows of data). In each row, there is the title of an identifer (a `NAME`) and then 41 columns that tell us whether the `NAME` includes a specific term with a '1' or a '0'. So, for example, in `data` `NAME1` has `gene1`, `gene2`, `gene3`, etc. like so:

```
      gene1  gene2 gene3
NAME1 1      0     1
NAME2 0      1     1
```

There are 41 potential genes in this code and I want to produce descriptive stats that explain where the overlaps lie. So, for example, how many NAMES have an overlap between gene1 and gene2, how many have both gene2 and gene3? I don't need to know which NAMES they are. Ideally, this would extend to combinations of 3 or more genes but this subset is very small so it's not actually essential. If I could just get stats on the number of times all two-gene combinations appear, that would be sufficient for this task.

I'm really stuck with this problem and not sure how to proceed. Any ideas out there? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use matrix multiplication:

```
m = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 4)
colnames(m) = paste0("gene", 1:4)

m
#      gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4
# [1,]     1     0     1     1
# [2,]     0     1     1     1


t(m) %*% m
#       gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4
# gene1     1     0     1     1
# gene2     0     1     1     1
# gene3     1     1     2     2
# gene4     1     1     2     2
```

You really only need half the matrix (since it's symmetric). This tells you that, e.g., `gene1` and `gene4` co-occurred in 1 row, but `gene3` and `gene4` co-occurred in 2 rows.

Answer (score 3):

An option is `crossprod`

```
crossprod(m, m)
```

#### data

```
m <- structure(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4")))
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I use this given that I have 41 possible identifiers?

Comment: @NewtoRcode. If `m` have all the 41 columns, it should give all the possible cases

Answer (score 2):

As I assume that `gene1` overlaps in all cases with `gene1` you might want:

```
crossprod(m, m) + crossprod(1-m, 1-m)
```

Comment: @Gregor--reinstateMonica-- It is not changing only the `diag` - e.g. `m <- matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ncol = 3)` . It depends on what is meant with *overlap* - have the same value or have a 1 at the same time.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had assumed OP wants to count 1 overlaps, this counts 0 overlaps as well. Perhaps OP can clarify.